# Php code echo Jquery a script dont work any idea?

Tags: php, jquery

I tried to call a jQuery script via php echo but it won't work and I don't know what to do.

I include this php code in my index.

```
<?php
    echo '<script> 
    $( "#hidebutton" ).click(function() {
    $( "#ID='.$id1.'" ).slideUp();
    });
    </script>';
?>
```

any idea?

- `#hidebutton` = a button
- `#ID=` = DIV + $id1 = id taken from database

the index page  (include idposthide.php is the jquery script^ up there^

```
// if post is not submitted display them all
$query = mysql_query("SELECT text, id,liked,dislike FROM post ORDER BY id DESC"); 
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$text =  $row['text'];
$vote = $row['liked'] ;
$vote2= $row['dislike'];
$id1 = $row['id'];

echo '<div id="ID='.$id1.'"><div id="myhidebutton"><input id="hidebutton" type="submit" value="hide"></div>'.'<div id="posts">'.'<h3>Κάποιος είπε:</h3>'.''.'<p><b><font size="3px">' 
. strip_tags($text) . '</font></b>'.' '.' '.'</p>';
echo '<hr>';
include "src/index.php";
include "idposthide.php";
echo'<br></div></div><br>' ;

}

}


?>
```

Comment: What exactly does "wont realy work" mean? What errors do you get?

Comment: Don't show us PHP code and tell us JavaScript doesn't work. Show us the JavaScript that doesn't work (also show us the HTML it is trying to operate on).

Comment: Give us the output of the php and the html of the element it is supposed to select.

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery is wrong. It should be:

```
  $( "#'.$id1.'" ).slideUp();
```

Jquery uses CSS-selectors. You should do `$("#id")` instead of `$("#ID=id")`. If you have an ID in your HTML like `<attr id="ID=xxx">`, correct it, IDs should not consist of "=".

In addition, is the button already loaded in the DOM for sure? Try:

```
$(function(){
  $( "#hidebutton" ).click(function() {
     $( "#ID='.$id1.'" ).slideUp();
  });
});
```

And last but not least, you could do this without echos:

```
?>
<script>
$(function(){
  $( "#hidebutton" ).click(function() {
    $( "#<?php echo $id; ?>" ).slideUp();
  });
});
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: well you this: [link](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Z9QaUiK7D-4/UidMqULtg5I/AAAAAAAAD18/0atZWAo__ZA/s640/pi.JPG)

Comment: "ID=" its a string,,, just the div name

Answer (score 1):

This should possibly work

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $( "#hidebutton" ).click(function() {
            $( "#<?php echo $id1 ?>" ).slideUp();
        });
    )(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, maybe You should write it like this:

```
<?php

echo '
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $( "#hidebutton" ).click(function() {
            $( "#'.$id1.'" ).slideUp();
        });
    });
    </script>';

?>
```

Comment: No, because the main problem is the "#ID=...". Jquery uses CSS-selectors. You should do $("#id") instead of $("#ID=id"). Or is he using an ID consiting of a "="?! In that case,  you are right and he should correct his HTML...

Comment: What have you changed? Why? This is a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer.

Comment: @Experience yeah, i noticed it 1 sec after adding this answer ;D

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos — It is your answer, you should know what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

May be this would be helpful

';
  echo '';
   echo        ' $("#productId").show(function(){' ;
   echo '$(this).next().fadeIn("slow").removeClass("valid").addClass("error");
            })';
          echo   ''; 
?>